# Logging Every Action to Database Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to store CRUD operations or any other activity such as login successful/unsuccessful attempts and any user account creation/deletion to a table in my database namely a `TRASACTION_LOG_TABLE`.

I have many controller and actions written , so i there any efficient way to do activity log.

How am I able to execute a function for every action or a group of actions in multiple controllers to call that particular function and add an entry to the database.

Comment: use database triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Activity Log:

you can create a common class and a static method in it like,

```
classname::setActivityLog(user_id,activity_msg,time);
```

and put this code in every action that you have written. **ex. actionUpdate, actionDelete etc.**

```
you can get the `user_id` from `Yii::app()->user->id`
put you custom activity message like "User #user_id created new item" etc.
time you can get it while saving into database.
```

create a table and model for the same like ActivityLog.This is what I did in my project.

**OR But this will have limitation like you cannot give custom message or custom action name**

You can create a [Class-Level Event Handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#class-level-event-handlers) in the [boostrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#bootstrap) process like this (most likely in the web.php configuration file, which holds the [configuration for the application](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html#application-configurations) object):

```
use yii\base\ActionEvent;
use yii\base\Controller;
use yii\base\Event;

$config = [
    ...
    'bootstrap'    => [
        ...
        function () {
            Event::on(Controller::class, Controller::EVENT_AFTER_ACTION, function (ActionEvent $event) {
                Yii::info('Called controller/action: ' . $event->action->id . '/' . $event->action->controller->id);
            });
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

Comment: But what if I have lots of different controllers with lots of actions associated with them it's going to be hard finding out on each action to write it manually.

Comment: check my answer now , but first solution is more feasible.